# Using VBA to open Access in full screen and in foreground

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 issues.

1. I am using VBA code to create a macro in PPT that opens an `Access` report. The macro works but does not open it in full screen. I have tried to add the `DoCmd.maximize` but not sure where to put it. So far it hasn't worked.
2. PPT won't let you save unless its a macro-enabled file. When I save it as one the macro works but opens in the background. How can I make it open in the foreground?

Here is what I have:

```
Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.Visible = True
accessApp.UserControl = True
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase ("C:\sts\263X.mdb")

accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "SKTL3P09A"
```